# How to seach for an input value in multiple arrays and return value and position utilizing one or more for-each loops

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 


public class JMUnit1Ch9 {


public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int[] sortedNumbers = new int[numbers.length]; 
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                numbers[i]= (int)(Math.random()*20); 

            }//end for

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sortedNumbers[i]=numbers[i]; 
        }//end for

        Arrays.sort(sortedNumbers);
        System.out.printf("%s%30s%n", "Unsorted Array", "Sorted Array");

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%-30.30s  %-30.30s%n", numbers[i], sortedNumbers[i]); 
            }
        System.out.printf("%s%n","Please enter a number to search for: "); 
        int numberSearch = stdIn.nextInt(); 
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i]==numberSearch)
            {
                System.out.printf("%nSearch Value: %d found at location: %d in the unsorted array",numberSearch,i); 

                found = true;
            }

            if (sortedNumbers[i]==numberSearch)
            {
                System.out.printf("%nSearch Value: %d found at location: %d in the sorted array",numberSearch,i);

            }
        }

        if (!found) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Search Value: %d was not found", numberSearch); 
        }

}

}
```

EDIT: I added the for loop based on the recommendation of a commenter and got it kind of to work, but without using else or the other if loops like I have if the value doesn't exist I don't want it so say so 10 times just once.

EDIT 2: Here's a link to the syllabus:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zufjp8sct0jftvw/CS%20219%20Unit%201%20Ch%209%20Assignment%20F2T%202015%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0

EDIT 3: Work perfectly now updated with the new code and changes. Thanks everyone for the editing and assistance.

Above is the code I have generated so far. My goals for this assignment which I have successfully completed above are to

- declare an array with a size of 10,
- fill the array with random numbers between 1-20,
- make a copy and sort utilizing java api,
- print a table showing the sorted and unsorted values
- and ask for a number to search the arrays for.

This issue I am running into is with the final goal which is to utilize the number input to search the arrays and provide an output for the search value and location in both the sorted and unsorted arrays utilizing a for each loop.

If anyone could give me some assistance figuring out how to accomplish this. My only ideas on this that have failed are to utilize an if else loop inside of the for each loop but I cannot utilize my `numberSearch` to find anything and am really at a loss for how to accomplish this.

Comment: Is your problem statement "find the indices of a given number in a sorted and unsorted array, both containing the same elements?" I kinda lost track halfway through it. You should try tweeting, it really teaches you to be concise and to the point.

Comment: to print an error message if not found - see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a number and print the array positions, and an error message if not found try

```
    System.out.printf("%s%n","Please enter a number to search for: "); 
    int numberSearch = stdIn.nextInt(); 
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i]==numberSearch)
        {
            System.out.printf("Search Value: %d found at location: %d 
                                     in the unsorted array",numberSearch,i); 
            found = true;
        }

        if (sortedNumbers[i]==numberSearch)
        {
            System.out.printf("Search Value: %d found at location: %d
                                      in the sorted array",numberSearch,i);
        }
    }

    if (!found) 
    {
        System.out.printf("Search Value: %d was not found", numberSearch); 
    }
```

Comment: I added %n to beginning of them this worked perfectly thanks a lot for your assistance @Scary Wombat.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `for-each` loop if you want to display the *index*, well you can - but you'd need a counter of some kind external to the loop (because a `for-each` loop hides the iterator). Just use a regular `for` loop. Like,

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == numberSearch) { 
     // n == numbers[i] == numberSearch
        System.out.printf("%d is at %d%n", numberSearch, i);
    }
}
```

There are further improvements that could be made, assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` to create your ten element array. Print your table, and then use [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) to find the element if present in the sorted array (which eliminates the need for `found`). Like,

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] numbers = IntStream.generate(() -> 1 + r.nextInt(20)).limit(10).toArray();
int[] sortedNumbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
Arrays.sort(sortedNumbers);

// Nice table.
System.out.printf("%s%30s%n", "Unsorted Array", "Sorted Array");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-30.30s  %-30.30s%n", numbers[i], sortedNumbers[i]);
}

System.out.println("Please enter a number to search for: ");
int numberSearch = stdIn.nextInt();
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedNumbers, numberSearch);
if (index > -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == numberSearch) {
            System.out.printf("Search Value: %d found at location: "
                    + "%d in the unsorted array%n", numberSearch,
                    i);
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Search Value: %d found at location: "
            + "%d in the sorted array%n", numberSearch, index);
} else {
    System.out.printf("Search Value: %d was not found%n", numberSearch);
}
```

Comment: I edited it based upon your recommendations but is there a way to not output for each iteration if the value doesn't exist in the arrays?

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyJudge Good news, my code doesn't output for each iteration if it doesn't exist in the array.